# Start Python in Background

Tags: python, windows, focus

So I have uTorrent set up to run a Python script when a torrent's state is changed so it can sort it. It all works fine except it takes focus from whatever I'm doing and it's crazy annoying.

I run it using `sorter.py <arguments>`. I'm on Windows 10. What can I do, if anything, to get this to run in the background and not take focus from what I'm doing?

I'm also sorry if this has already been answered but I couldn't find anything that worked.

Comment: Just run it as-is. A regular Python program has a single thread by default which will run for the duration of the program. Use a while loop to continuously execute program logic.

Comment: I don't think you understand @MalikBrahimi. It opens a new console window, which takes focus from whatever I'm doing. So for example, if I'm typing something and looking elsewhere (which I do for 90% of my typing), and it takes focus, everything I write from then on is into the console window.

Answer (score 1):

Running with `pythonw` (or changing extension to `.pyw` which is the same) may help.

`pythonw.exe` doesn't create a console window but I dunno about focus. It doesn't create any windows by default, either, so it shouldn't steal it.

Comment: Can you change the wording a bit there to "running `pythonw.exe` doesn't automatically create a console window"?

Comment: A .pyw script could call `AllocConsole` or `AttachConsole` to get a console window. In either case, `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe`, the console client never creates the console window. It merely attaches to the host process, `conhost.exe`, that creates the window. However, `python[w].exe` may call `CreateWindowEx` to actually create a top-level window (most likely using Tk, Qt, etc).

Comment: @eryksun we're talking about a script that's specifically intended to not affect existing windows. Thus it's very unlikely to call any funny stuff like that. The comment is still useful though in the remote case it does.